# Rename power plans in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, power

Is there a reliable way to rename power plans in Windows 7?

Creating new ones with a new names is not too hard, but some systems have dozens of power settings (including advanced settings) in each plan, and so recreating them exactly can be tedious and time consuming.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UPDATE: There is a more "secure" way to do it. Here is how:

Open an elevated Command Prompt (type "cmd" in the search box, in Start menu, right click in the cmd.exe icon, and Run as Administrator).

Type `powercfg list`
This will list all current power plans.

Copy the GUID of the plan that you want to rename and type:

```
powercfg -changename GUID "new name"
```

---

*You can find the Power plans in the registry, under this key:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\User\PowerSchemes
If you select each of the entries, they should have a key called FriendlyName.
Editing the value of this entry will change the name of the power plan.
To edit the registry just press windows key, and in the search box type "regedit"
If it is your first time editing the regedit be extra careful and do not change anything else, you can completely ruin the OS if you edit the wrong value.*

Comment: Thanks Ballantin.  Have you successfully used this technique without any side-effects?  I see no reason why it shouldn't work without problems, but it would be good to know if you've had any side-effects.

Comment: Updated with another, more secure method.